# Conditional emebed html between PHP code blocks + setting cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I started studying PHP few weeks ago and I'm a little bit confused with conditional embed HTML between PHP code blocks and setting cookies. What I want to do is a simple code that checks your name, password and e-mail, sets cookie (if they are valid); when you have already logged in, you should see "log out" button. So, my code:

```
    <?php
    if (($_POST['name'] == 'admin')  and ($_POST['pass'] == 'admin') and ($_POST['mail'] == 'admin@gmail.com')) {
    setcookie("Test","Value"); 
    echo "Success!!! <br/>";
    }


    if ($_POST['logout']) {
    setcookie("Test", "", time() - 3600);
    echo "Goodbye!";

    }

    ?>

    <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['Test'])) :
    ?>
       <input type="submit" value="logout"/><br/>

    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['Test'])) :
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="pass"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="mail"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="go"/><br/>
    <?php endif ?>
```

However, I can't figure out how to make it work properly: when I enter correct username, password and mail, I don't see "logout" button, there's still a form and i need to enter username again to finally see "logout". Second problem, when I press "logout", nothing happens. I guess I can't set the cookie because headers were already sent, but I can't figure out how to rewrite it.

Comment: Despites some `undefined index` error, your code works well on my local server.. I successfully had the `logout` button upon right credentials. The button doesn't work though. Having a look at it.

Comment: You appear to be assuming that `setcookie` affects the `$_COOKIES` collection for the **current** request, and not just subsequent ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has per @RowlandShaw stated in the comment, `setcookie()` will affect only the future requests, not the current one.

Here is your corrected code:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['pass']) && isset($_POST['mail']))
    {
        if (($_POST['name'] == 'admin')  and ($_POST['pass'] == 'admin') and ($_POST['mail'] == 'admin@gmail.com')) {
            setcookie("Test","Value"); 
            echo "Success!!! <br/>";
            echo '<form action="" method="POST">'.
                     '<input type="submit" value="logout" name="logout"/><br/>'.
                 '</form>';
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
        setcookie("Test", "", time() - 3600);
        echo "Goodbye!";
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">Login back</a>';

    }
}
else
{
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="pass"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="mail"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="go"/><br/>
<?php } ?>
```

You will have to create a link to the same page so the cookie modification are taken into account. Also, you didn't set up a name on your logout button nor did you specify that the logout action is a `POST` request by adding the `<form>` tag (it's `GET` by default) that made `$_POST['logout']` never set.